# XCode8: UICollectionView edge-to-edge, Editing constraints in One Trait Variation (Size Class) breaks other Trait Variations

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, xcode8, size-classes

I am having an infuriating issue with Xcode interface builder.  I have a storyboard where one view controller has a UICollectionView that's edge to edge to the View Controller's Root View. The root View has Descendant constraints of -16 and -16 for Leading and Trailing space to the UICollectionView.

When I switch to the other size class (Or Trait Variation as it's now called), the Leading and Trailing margins become -20, -20.   If I adjust them to be edge to edge, then the other Trait Variation becomes inset by 4 pixels on each side.  So editing the constraints in one variation screws up the other variation, and thus all my internal calculation logic is off for the cells.

So i can not simultaneously satisfy the constraints in multiple trait variations all at the same time, and have my UICollectionView just be edge-to-edge without any padding around it.

I tried remaking all constraints.  Same issue.

I tried turning off Trait Variations on the storyboard itself.  Same issue.

EDIT: Also tried adding an "Intermediary View" (also edge-to-edge) and housing my UICollectionView inside it.  Makes no difference.

I noticed that the negative inset amount has to be different on each device factor.  On some it's -16 -16, on some it's -20, -20, on iPad it's -8, -8.   So since these are static values, then how can you embed a scrollview edge to edge reliably, without fiddling with the constraints programmatically at runtime?

I can fix one device screen size, but it breaks the other screen sizes.

Also, i don't actually want to use size classes, but even if i turn off size classes, i still don't get one unified view for editing the constraints in one place.  So this effectively multiplies the work i have to do by 6 times.  This is costing me a ridiculous amount of time already.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a cheap and easy solution.  My problem was: my Leading and Trailing constraints were to the Margin, and not to the superview directly.  The margin is what differs across size classes.   So I modified my 2 constraints:  Leading and Trailing, disabling the "Relative to Margin" option on each.  Instructions here:  [UIViewController Nested View To Screen Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383287/uiviewcontroller-nested-view-to-screen-edge)

Now i get a consistent behaviour on every screen size (no margins around collection view).